# unable to run python programs from windows 10 cmd

Tags: python-2.7

This is the path where python is installed on my computer `A:\software installation\python` and the same path has been added to the system path in Environment variables.
My scripts are stored in `A:\python programs` but when I try to execute from the Windows command prompt (cmd) there is no output as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Try first to execute it by defining the full path: `A:\software installation\python\python.exe hello.py`

Comment: same problem. No output.

Comment: Could you share your `hello.py` ?

Comment: It's only one line. `print "programming is fun"`

Comment: Try `python --help`... Will it work for you?

Comment: I get `usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...                                                       Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables): ` followed by various arguments like -B, -c, -d, -E and so on.

Comment: Could be related: https://bugs.python.org/issue1602 reprint your text (if it was copy-pasted)

Comment: Reinstalled python on the default location (C:\python27). Still the same problem.

Comment: What's about `python -c 'print "programming is fun"'` ?

Comment: There was some problem with my Internet, hence the delayed response. I see a blank line with no writing.

Comment: @AlokY, so did waiting helped?

Comment: If the Python interpreter isn't found on the path, Windows will signal an error and the Command Prompt window will say "'python' is not recognized [...]".

If the script 'hello.py' is not found, Python will signal an error and it will say "python: can't open file 'hello.py' [...]".

What is happening above is that the script has been run and the script did not print anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your environment variable path, like `C:\Python27`.

1. Check your system for the installation path
2. Copy the path
3. Go to my computer properties => advance system setting
4. In the Advanced tab => Environment variable => click on the path, then click on `new` and paste the path
5. Click `ok` and restart the cmd

All done :)

Answer (score 13):

If you have installed Python 3.7 or above try using keyword "py" instead of "python" on cmd. It worked for me.(I have python 3.7 32bit installed in windows 10 operating system)

Comment: this is tagged python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it using the following steps:

1. Right-click the file you want to run.
2. Select "always run using this program" to make this default, to avoid doing this again for other running other python files.
3. Browse and select the python 3.6 (or 2.7) interpreter file.