# I'm getting a error when I run my setup.py on cx_freeze 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert my GUI application I created using Tkinter to a .exe file and the GUI Application consists of libraries like **pandas** and **NumPy**.

I'm using the **cx_Freeze** as my library of choice for converting my GUI Application to .exe file and I'm currently using the python version: **'Python 3.7.7'**.

And I'm also a bit doubted that this error might be caused because I'm using an earlier version of python(**I'm using Anaconda distribution's python as my python interpreter**) and I've been trying for many days for a solution but those attempts failed.

If anyone can find a solution for my problem please help me to know the solution.

This is the setup.py code:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import pandas
import numpy

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("app.py", base=base, icon="myicon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Correlation-Generator",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","pandas","numpy"], "include_files":["myicon.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "A GUI Application which takes in metrics for generating a correlation value",
    executables = executables
    )
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer_exe.py", line 60, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 342, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 217, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 645, in Freeze
    self._WriteModules(fileName, self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 536, in _WriteModules
    sourcePackageDir = os.path.dirname(module.file)
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\ntpath.py", line 221, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\Users\RAJ\Anaconda3\envs\correlation-generator\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message please?

Comment: Definetly I will edit my message

Comment: Hey bertil I added the error.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861349/python-script-to-executable-with-cx-freeze-exe-does-nothing

Comment: Hey @Atlas435 I tried thier solution but it doesnt work

Comment: Try not including numpy and pandas explicitly, cx_freeze is pretty good at figuring out which standard libraries to include. I also had a tkinter GUI using pandas and numpy that I converted using cx_freeze. In my case I didn't include the names of these packages in the executables dict, so instead of {"packages":["tkinter","pandas","numpy"] I just had {"packages":["tkinter"]. Rest of the code pretty much identical and it worked like a charm. Python 3.6, anaconda 5.2.0.